# javascript window.open doesn't work here

Tags: javascript, window, window.open

I need to open this urls in a new tab. Right now they are opening in the same page.

```
var data = [  
    {title: "1", url: "gallery1.html"},  
    {title: "2", url: "gallery2.html"},  
    {title: "3", url: "gallery2.html"},
```

My knowledge in javascript is very short. I tried things like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>    
window.open(url);      
</script>
```

or

```
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.example.url; }) 
.attr("xlink:target", "_blank") 
.attr("xlink:title", function(d) { return d.example.title; });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

This will open it in a new page.

[`_blank` is a special keyword](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context-names) that will tell `.open` to open in a new page.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n780rz9o/

Comment: @kajihood `data.forEach(link => open(link.url, "_blank"))` This will open all links in your array.

Comment: where I have to put that?

Comment: @kajihood Put it wherever you want to open a new page. If you have no programming experience I encourage you to do some readings on basic HTML5 apis.

Comment: Can you please put an example with my code? I tried to copy your demo and it says syntax error.

Comment: @kajihood Probably because I used ES6 syntax. Try converting it back to ES5 if you are using an older browser.

Comment: how do i do that? as i said my knowledge is very short here.

Answer (score 0):

To loop trough your array do sth like this:

```
data.forEach(function(elem){
window.open(elem.url,"_blank");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, where do I have to put that? I'm trying to put it like this and it doesn't work

Comment: It just still doing the same